# Has Jean-Claude Van Damme really no memories of filming the movie Knock Off?

Tags: production, knock-off, jean-claude-van-damme

I recently watched Knock Off and [came across this little quote](http://birthmoviesdeath.com/2014/02/05/the-underrated-insanity-of-tsui-hark-and-jean-claude-van-dammes-knock-off/):

> It also features Jean Claude Van Damme’s best performance outside of
>   JCVD… not that he’d recall as he’s suggested he was so coked out at
>   the time he doesn’t remember filming it.

It's from [this review](http://birthmoviesdeath.com/2014/02/05/the-underrated-insanity-of-tsui-hark-and-jean-claude-van-dammes-knock-off/) but it's the only reference I find about Van Damme not remembering shooting the movie. Has it ever been said in an interview or is it just some exaggerated (although Van Damme really was addicted to drugs one time in his career) nonsense

Comment: [Research](http://news.harvard.edu/gazette/1998/03.12/ResearchersSeeH.html) definitely [shows](http://www.smh.com.au/articles/2004/02/20/1077072807347.html?from=storyrhs) that cocaine use does have the potential to cause memory issues. Not sure if that's the case here.

Answer (score 2):

Short of a quote from Jean Claude van Damme directly, there isn't going to be any way of actually confirming this. Looking at the site you quoted obviously reveals that the author of that article believes that he doesn't remember making it - whether this is something the author has picked up from conversation. It doesn't cite *how* the author of the article knows, though.

I've had a look around and don't see anything obvious that backs up him having no memory of recording the show. It's certainly not mentioned on IMDB for either the movie or the actor.

Cocaine can effect your memory, and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Claude_Van_Damme) backs up that during that period of time he was certainly taking a lot of it. He was also diagnosed bi-polar, that's certainly not going to help in the memory department either